# Alarm using database and service to trigger Notification

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an application which is to trigger notification at specific time..i am trying to store time in database.And a service to set the Alarm from database.After the Notification next alarm has to set. Iam trying the following Code ...But not Working.. Please Help...
Thanks ..
Sorry for My Bad English..

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver 
{    
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){   

         PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
         PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
         wl.acquire();

         // Put here YOUR code.
         Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

         wl.release();
     }

     public void SetAlarm(Context context){

         AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);

         // Intent i = new Intent("mypackage.START_ALARM");
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
         System.out.println("Started");

         am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 2, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
     }

     public void CancelAlarm(Context context){
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
         PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
         AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         alarmManager.cancel(sender);
     }
}
```

---

```
public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver
{   

    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){   
        Toast.makeText(context, "Started", 3);
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")){
            alarm.SetAlarm(context);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Service**

```
public class YourService extends Service
{
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();       
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
         alarm.SetAlarm(YourService.this);
         return START_STICKY;
    }


    public void onStart(Context context,Intent intent, int startId){
        alarm.SetAlarm(context);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is my Manifest File..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testfont"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission> 


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="Alarm"></receiver>


        <receiver android:name=".AutoStart">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>            
    </application>

</manifest>
```

this Program is to Set the Alarm after 2 minutes But not get any response while testing in Emulator. If this Works I am planning to write the Database code to fetch the time  Inside the SetAlarm  method.. is this idea Good or not Please Help..

Comment: Feel free to explain what "not working" means for you.

Comment: Sir i had Specified the problem ....

Comment: I have the same question. Could you please post your answer on how you managed to parse the date and time from the database?